# Jquery not working when in seperate js file

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

I can't get my jquery code to work when inserting it into a separate js file and not having it in the html. Right now it looks like this

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/480.js" media="screen and (max-width: 480px)" defer</script>
```

inside "480.js" it looks like this

```
document.getElementById("navbar").style.display = "none" {
  $('#navbar').hide()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the documentation, a good resource is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script

As you can see there, there is no `media` attribute for the `<script>` tag. You can not just invent attributes yourself and assume it works.

You should remove your `480.js` file if the above content is all you have written there. Because that's not valid javascript and will only create errors.

To solve your problem, there is no javascript needed. As you can do that all with pure CSS. (See and play with this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/u19s432z/)

Just add the following to your css

```
#navbar {
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { 
    #navbar {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't know if you were able to do that with the `<script>` tag. Though the code isn't done I was just trying stuff out to see if it works but it doesn't. I am trying to make a hamburger icon that is clickable for phones but not for desktop.

Comment: @True see this https://jsfiddle.net/u19s432z/ you can resize the viewport and the `#navbar` hides and shows depending on the screen width. If it does not work for you the problem is somewhere else. Maybe you have used inline-styles or other specificity issues in css.